# Azure Devops - Muliple Repos Triggers

Tags: github, azure-devops

Has the Following Feature has been implemented for Gihub Repos yet?**strong text**

Multi-repo triggers
You can specify multiple repositories in one YAML file and cause a pipeline to trigger by updates to any of the repositories. This feature is useful, for instance, in the following scenarios:

You consume a tool or a library from a different repository. You want to run tests for your application whenever the tool or library is updated.
You keep your YAML file in a separate repository from the application code. You want to trigger the pipeline every time an update is pushed to the application repository.
With this update, multi-repo triggers will only work for Git repositories in Azure Repos. They don't work for GitHub or Bitbucket repository resources.

SAMPLE :

trigger:

- main

resources:
repositories:
- repository: tools
type: git
name: MyProject/tools
ref: main
trigger:
branches:
include:
- main
- release

Answer (score 0):

As per Microsoft official sprint 173 updates 2020, this is achiveable using resources tag inside your yaml.

Here is an example that shows how you can setup an auto trigger inside your yaml pipeline based on any change in any other repos inside the same project and even other projects inside Azure DevOps as well.

Sample:

```
trigger:
  - main

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: tools
      type: git
      name: MyProject/tools
      ref: main
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - main
            - release
```

In the above code snippet:

- **main** branch in the self repo containing the YAML file
- **main** or **release** branches in **tools** repo

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-173-update#multi-repo-triggers) for official documentation form Microsoft for further details.

Hope that solution works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Repository resource triggers only work for Azure Repos Git repositories in the same organization at present. They do not work for GitHub or Bitbucket repository resources.

[image]

Refer to this official doc for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers

If you would like this feature to be supported, create a feature request: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest